# Magento CE 1.7 Cron Job Assistance

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, cron

I am using this following script for Magento CE 1.7
http://www.ecomdev.org/2010/06/07/how-to-schedule-the-future-product-activation.html

In my cpanel I went to advance-->Cron Jobs

created: 5 * * * */home/username/public_html/testsite/cron.sh

The products are not updating like they should be. I have it set for every 5 minutes. Can someone take a look for me please and let me know what I am doing wrong. I am new to cron jobs. Obviously something is not set correctly. Am I suppose to add anything in the cron.sh or cron.php??

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with cpanel but are you not missing the start of your commandOne of the following commands should work for you:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /[magento_path]/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash /[magento_path]/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /[magento_path]/cron.php
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /[magento_path]/cron.php
```

I would suggest if cpanel allows you to send an email with the results of your cron then you should also set this up.

Comment: Do you know if I am suppose to add something to either the cron.sh or cron.php file? The instructions say "And don’t forget to setup Magento cron in your system crontab" I do not understand what he means by doing this...

Comment: Please explain it is not updating itself in magento automatically. I did what was suggested. It is going through on my sever.